# Inheriting quasiconvexity from convex function after re-parametrisation of space into the Stiefel manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

Consider a function $f(S): \mathcal{S} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is the convex cone of all positive semidefinite complex $M\times M$ Hermitian matrices.
The function $f(\cdot )$ is concave over $\mathcal{S}$.

I now define another function $g(L): \mathcal{RSM}(M,N) \to \mathbb{R}$ where $\mathcal{RSM}(M,N)$ is the relaxed Stiefel manifold in $\mathbb{C}^M$, i.e., if $L \in \mathcal{RSM}(M,N)$, then $L^\mathrm{H} L \preceq I_N$. The notation $A \preceq B$ means that $A-B$ is negative semi-definite. The function $g(L)$ is defined as $g(L)=f(LL^{\mathrm{H}})$.

My question is concerning what convexity-properties of $g(\cdot )$ that can be $in \; general$ inherited from $f(\cdot)$. For several different $f(\cdot)$ I have observed that the function $g(\cdot )$ is quasi-convex over $\mathcal{RSM}(M,N)$. Is this true in general?

If no general conclusions can be made, I am in particular interested in the function
$$f(S) = \log (\det (I+HSH^\mathrm{H})),$$
where $H$ is an $P \times M$ matrix where $P>N$.

Moreover, I am even more interested in the function 
$$f(S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_K) = \log (\det (I+\sum_{k=1}^K H_kS_kH_k^\mathrm{H}))$$
in which case, the notation above needs slight revision, i.e.,  $f(\cdot,\ldots,\cdot): \mathcal{S}^K \to \mathbb{R}$ etc.

Finally, $A^\mathrm{H}$ denotes the conjugate transpose operator.

Comment: The function of interest to you turns out to be geodesically convex on the set of (strictly) positive hermitian matrices. For a proof, please see Corollary 2.11 of our paper: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/140978168  -- on a different note, this function is not quasi-convex in the Euclidean sense

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have read your paper but failed to see how the reduced rank is entering the problem. I have the feeling we are not studying the same problem. Could you please expand your answer? We have also tried numerically over a long simulation to came up with a counterexample when the quasiconvexity in the euclidean sense fails. It would be of a great help for me if you expand also on this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The paper I linked indeed works only for strictly +ve matrices, not for semidefinite ones (because in that case, we no longer have a clean geometry). There seems to be some mismatch btw in your question above, because you say $f$ is convex, however the determinant is not convex on $S$, so I am not sure what you are after.

Comment: Sorry, the function f(S) is concave and equal to log det().

Comment: The function $f(S) = \det(I + S)$ is not quasi-convex; neither is $\log f$; it is easy to find numerical counterexamples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but we are interested in the convexity-properties of $g(\cdot)$.

Comment: I see; I misread it then. IMHO the question could be improved by just stating it shortly as: "Is the map $S \mapsto \log\det(I+SS^*)$ quasi-convex?". It turns out (as a simple numerical counterexample will show) that this map is also not quasi-convex (I tried, however, without the assumption $SS^* \le I$, with that assumption it seems q-c holds for the map mentioned in this comment).